# help pages not available, programs don't start

Tags: software-center

I am a newbie, purchased mini pc with Ubuntu preinstalled uname says 17.22.04.1-ubuntu
Firefox and Thunderbird work fine.
Click on help some help pages not found
Click on installed programs. Some work others don't start. For example disk management shows small examples and installation information.
Have I purchased a limited version of Ubuntu or am I not using it right?
I am willing to read manuals and learn if pointed to what I should do
Tom George

Comment: You've provided specifics. The `uname` command tells you about the Linux kernel, and very little about the actual OS you're using. Your provided detail shows 22.04.1 which means your system is very outdated & 22.04 if that's what you're using, however if that came from the `uname` command that isn't what you're actually running but packaging info only !  (ie. only 22.04 is relevant there, the .1 has a different meaning). Detail as to HWE or GA kernel stack you didn't show (eg. 22.04 is a LTS release thus has kernel stack choice; GA = 5.15, HWE = 6.5 currently, with OEM options too).

Comment: You should provide the full command & output of a command you wish to help us interpret.  You've not indicated if it's a Server or Desktop, though mention of apps like `firefox` imply its got a Desktop system installed. I'd likely use `lsb_release -a` to view system detail (ie. linux-standard-base show -all) though it provides little anyway.. `uname` will reveal some kernel stack details (eg. 5.15 if using GA, 6.5 if using HWE, other options of 5.19, 6.2 show you're behind on applying security fixes; other options also exist where OEM is usually also shown giving clues).

Comment: There of course is more you can explore too, but it'll depend on what you actually want to know/learn. You mention *help* but didn't mention Ubuntu product which is useful for help as different resources exist; eg. Server docs are mostly online & read via HTML, but specific apps have their own help, or are you after Desktop help; where you may need to be specific as to help for which app (*that is most important for desktops!*)  If you have Ubuntu installed; I'd not worry about a *limited* version, as differences are mostly just default packages.. if however its Ubuntu based that's different.